# JQRelcopy not working in renderPartial()

Tags: php, jquery, yii, yii-extensions

I'm using JQRelcopy extension in my pop-up view. When I'm using render(), extension is working fine but each time when I open the color box it POST old values to the controller. 
If I use renderPartial() it posts new values each time to the controller when I open color box, but extension (JQRelcopy) does not clone fields.

This is where I'm using extenion in view:

```
Yii::import('ext.jqrelcopy.JQRelcopy');

$this->widget('ext.jqrelcopy.JQRelcopy',array(
    'id' => 'copylink',
    'removeText' => '<i class="icon-remove" style="margin-left: 1px;"></i>',
    'removeHtmlOptions' => array('style'=>'color:red; margin-left: 45px'),
    'jsAfterCloneComplete' => 'initializeTimePicker()',
    'jsAfterNewId' => JQRelcopy::afterNewIdDatePicker(Util::getCustomDatePicker($briefingEquipment, 0, $minDate, $maxDate)),

    'options' => array(
        'copyClass' => 'copy',
        'limit' => 10,
        'clearInputs' => true,
        'excludeSelector' => '.skipcopy',
    )
));
```

This is my Controller code:

```
public function actionShowEquipment()
{
    $this->layout = "//layouts/popup";

    $equipmentConflicts = '';
    $briefingId = $_POST['briefingId'];
    $briefingDate = $_POST['briefingDate'];
    $briefingEndDate = isset($_POST['briefingEndDate']) ? $_POST['briefingEndDate'] : '';
    $serializeBriefingEquipments = isset($_POST['briefingEquipments']) ? $_POST['briefingEquipments'] : '';

    $equipment = CHtml::listData(Equipment::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name');
    $briefingCenter = BriefingCenter::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->currentBriefingCenterId);

    if ($briefingId) {
     $briefingEquipmentArr = BriefingEquipment::model()->findAll('briefing_id = :bId', array(':bId' => $briefingId));

        if (!$briefingEquipmentArr) {
            $briefingEquipmentArr[] = new BriefingEquipment();
        }
    } else if ($serializeBriefingEquipments) {
        $serializeBriefingEquipments = unserialize($serializeBriefingEquipments);
    }

    $briefing = Briefing::model()->findByPk($briefingId);

    if (!empty($briefing->scheduled_date) && !empty($briefing->scheduled_end_date)) {
        $minDate = $briefing->scheduled_date;
        $maxDate = $briefing->scheduled_end_date;
    } else {
        $minDate = $briefingDate;
        $maxDate = $briefingEndDate;
    }

    echo $this->renderPartial('edit/equipment', array(
        'briefing' => array(
            'briefingId' => $briefingId,
            'briefingDate' => $briefingDate,
            'briefingEndDate' => $briefingEndDate,
        ),
        'minDate' => strtotime($minDate),
        'maxDate' =>  strtotime($maxDate),
        'briefingEquipmentArr' => $briefingEquipmentArr,
        'equipments' => $equipment,
        'briefingCenter' => $briefingCenter,
        'serializeBriefingEquipments' => $serializeBriefingEquipments,
        'dateFormat' => Yii::app()->user->currentBriefingCenterDateFormat,
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of the render and renderPartial, I used render and the extension work perfectly fine.
Following is the difference between render and renderPartial which I've taken fro Stackoverflow.

**render()** is commonly used to render a view that corresponds to what a user sees as a "page" in your application. It first renders the view you have specified and then renders the layout for the current controller action (if applicable), placing the result of the first render into the layout. It then performs output processing (which at this time means automatically inserting any necessary  tags and updating dynamic content) and finally outputs the result.

**renderPartial()** is commonly used to render a "piece" of a page. The main difference from render() is that this method does not place the results of the render in a layout. By default, it also does not perform output processing, but you can override this behavior using the $processOutput parameter.